# How to use spring.security.oauth2.client with SOAP calls, initially sent by org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-ws, spring-oauth2

We have a Spring Boot microservice that does the SOAP call to the external system using `org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate`.

Now the system would be protected with `Keycloak`, so all the request need to beak the auth token.

If it was a REST API, I would just replace the pre-existed `RestTemplate` with `OAuth2RestTemplate`. But how to instrument the calls initially done by the `org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate` ?

So, I understand, I should put the `authentication` header manually with value `'Bearer ....token there...'`. How I can retrieve that part manually to put it into the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by

1. Existing library code, based on `org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate`, so large and huge for rewriting it using `WebClient`, compatible with OAuth2 SpringSecurity or use depricated `OAuth2RestTemplate`
2. The webservice we previously communicated with, turns into protected with `Gravitee` and accepts queries with JWT tokens only. So, the only change here is to add the `Authentication` header with `'Bearer ....token there...'`
3. We initiate the call from the scheduled jo in the microservice. So, it should be getting token from the `Keycloak` before the request and be able to update it with time. No one does the explicit authorization like in the frontend, so the OAuth2 client should use `client-id` and `client-secret` to connect with no human involved

### The Solution

1. At the beginning, we define the Interceptor to the SOAP calls, that will pass the token as a header, via a Supplier function taking it wherever it can be taken:

   ```
    public class JwtClientInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

    private final Supplier<String> jwtToken;

    public JwtClientInterceptor(Supplier<String> jwtToken) {
        this.jwtToken = jwtToken;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) {
        SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) messageContext. getRequest();
        SoapHeader soapHeader = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
        soapHeader.addHeaderElement(new QName("authorization"))
                .setText(String. format("Bearer %s", jwtToken.get()));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Exception ex) throws WebServiceClientException {

    }
   ```

   }
2. Then pass it to the template in addition to other pre-existed interceptor to be called in config class:

   ```
    protected WebServiceTemplate     buildWebServiceTemplate(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller,
                                                             HttpComponentsMessageSender messageSender, String uri,     Supplier<String> jwtToken) {
        WebServiceTemplate template = new WebServiceTemplate();
        template.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        template.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        template.setMessageSender(messageSender);
        template.setDefaultUri(uri);
        ClientInterceptor[] clientInterceptors =     ArrayUtils.addAll(template.getInterceptors(), new Logger(), new     JwtClientInterceptor(jwtToken));

        template.setInterceptors(clientInterceptors);
        return template;
    }
   ```
3. Then add the Spring Security Oath2 Client library

   ```
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:5.2.1.RELEASE'
   ```
4. We create `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService` bean, that uses a standard `ClientRegistrationRepository` (the repository is initiated through usage of `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation on the `@Configuration` class, but please double check about that)

   ```
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService     oAuth2AuthorizedClientService(ClientRegistrationRepository     clientRegistrationRepository) {
            return  new     InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
       }
   ```
5. Then create a OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager

   ```
        @Bean
        public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
                ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

            Authentication authentication = new Authentication()     {
                @Override
                public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
                    GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new GrantedAuthority() {
                        @Override
                        public String getAuthority() {
                            return "take_a_needed_value_from_property";
                        }
                    };
                    return Arrays.asList(grantedAuthority);
                }

                @Override
                public Object getCredentials() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public Object getDetails() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public Object getPrincipal() {
                    return new Principal() {
                        @Override
                        public String getName() {
                            return "our_client_id_from_properties";
                    }
                };
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isAuthenticated() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {

            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "take_a_needed_name_from_properties";
            }
        };
    //we need to emulate Principal there, as other classes relies on it. In fact, Principal isn't needed for the app which is a client and just do the call, as nothing is authorized in the app against this Principal itself

            OAuth2AuthorizationContext oAuth2AuthorizationContext     =     OAuth2AuthorizationContext.withClientRegistration(clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId("keycloak")).
                    principal(authentication).
                    build();
                oAuth2AuthorizationContext.getPrincipal().setAuthenticated(true);
            oAuth2AuthorizationContext.getAuthorizedClient();

            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =     OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().
            //refreshToken().
            clientCredentials(). //- we use this one according to our set up
            //authorizationCode().
                    build();

            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oAuth2AuthorizedClientService =     oAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository); //use the bean from before step here

            AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                    new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                            clientRegistrationRepository,     oAuth2AuthorizedClientService);
            OAuth2AuthorizedClient oAuth2AuthorizedClient =     authorizedClientProvider.authorize(oAuth2AuthorizationContext);
                authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
          oAuth2AuthorizedClientService.saveAuthorizedClient(oAuth2AuthorizedClient, 
      oAuth2AuthorizationContext.getPrincipal());
      //this step is needed, as without explicit authorize call, the 
      //oAuth2AuthorizedClient isn't initialized in the service

            return authorizedClientManager;
        }
   ```
6. Provide a method for supplied function that can be called each time to retrieve the JWT token from the security stuff (repository and manager). Here it should be auto-updated, so we just call for retrieving it

   ```
     public Supplier<String> getJwtToken() {
            return () -> {
                OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient("keycloak", "we_havePout_realm_there_from_the_properties");
                return     authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
            };
        }
   ```
7. Pass this `Consumer` to the `@Bean`, defining the `WebServiceTemplate`'s

   ```
     @Bean
        public Client client(@Qualifier("Sender1") HttpComponentsMessageSender bnfoMessageSender,
                             @Qualifier("Sender2")     HttpComponentsMessageSender uhMessageSender) {
            WebServiceTemplate sender1= buildWebServiceTemplate(buildSender1Marshaller(),     sender1MessageSender, properties.getUriSender1(),getJwtToken());
            WebServiceTemplate sender2 = buildWebServiceTemplate(buildSender2Marshaller(), sender2MessageSender, properties.getUriSender2(),getJwtToken());
            return buildClient(buildRetryTemplate(), sender1, sender2);
        }
   ```
8. We add Spring Security Client values to `application.yaml` in order to configure it.

   ```
    spring:
     security:
        oauth2:
          client:
            provider:
              keycloak:
                issuer-uri: https://host/keycloak/auth/realms/ourrealm
            registration:
              keycloak:
                client-id: client_id
                client-secret: client-secret-here
                authorization-grant-type: client_credentials     //need to add explicitly, otherwise would try other grant-type by default and never get the token!
                client-authentication-method: post //need to have this explicitly, otherwise use basic that doesn't fit best the keycloak set up
                scope: openid //if your don't have it, it checks all available scopes on url like https://host/keycloak/auth/realms/ourrealm/ .well-known/openid-configuration keycloak and then sends them as value of parameter named 'scope' in the query for retrieving the token; that works wrong on our keycloak, so to replace this auto-picked value, we place the explicit scopes list here
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you can get current request token using `RequestContextHolder` class and add into soap request header.

```
String token = ((ServletRequestAttributes)(RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())).getRequest().getHeader("Authorization");
```

Also I would suggest use Webservice interecptor instead of adding header in each web service request call.